# How to stop Vim markdown syntax from highlighting as italic asterisks used to denote bold?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, markdown

Using Vim 7.4 on Windows in ConEmu (though I have seen the same thing on other platforms/setups), I notice that the syntax highlighting is matching the beginning and ending double-asterisks as italic sub-regions within the bold region that they denote. This is an eyesore:

[image: Vim markdown highlighting asterisks as italics in bold area]

After digging around, I think I have found the source of this problem (from `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/markdown.vim`):

```
syn region markdownItalic start="\S\@<=\*\|\*\S\@=" end="\S\@<=\*\|\*\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
syn region markdownItalic start="\S\@<=_\|_\S\@=" end="\S\@<=_\|_\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
syn region markdownBold start="\S\@<=\*\*\|\*\*\S\@=" end="\S\@<=\*\*\|\*\*\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart,markdownItalic
syn region markdownBold start="\S\@<=__\|__\S\@=" end="\S\@<=__\|__\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart,markdownItalic
syn region markdownBoldItalic start="\S\@<=\*\*\*\|\*\*\*\S\@=" end="\S\@<=\*\*\*\|\*\*\*\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
syn region markdownBoldItalic start="\S\@<=___\|___\S\@=" end="\S\@<=___\|___\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
```

And farther down:

```
hi def link markdownItalic                htmlItalic
hi def link markdownBold                  htmlBold
hi def link markdownBoldItalic            htmlBoldItalic
```

As you can see, the bold accepts italics as a subregion. The problem is if I remove `markdownItalic` from the `contains=`, this:

[image: bold and italic working]

no longer works right:

[image: bold and italic goofed up]

even though it fixed the other problem. I also trying substituting `\S` in the regexes for italic to be `[^*]` but that didn't work either. Also, installing [Plastic Boy's Markdown plugin](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) didn't fix it.

Any ideas on how to get around this annoying case?

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is why the start and end are being matched as the same thing with an or in the middle. It would seem to me that one have of the or should be for start and one half for end. But then again, when you get regexes this complicated, it gets hard to know what all is going on and why...

Comment: Figure out any solutions here?

Answer (score 1):

So this basic concept does work:

> I also trying substituting `\S` in the regexes for italic to be `[^*]` but that didn't work either.

Just copy `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/markdown.vim` into `~/.vim/syntax/` and change the two `syn region markdownItalic...` lines to be

```
syn region markdownItalic start="[^* ]\@<=\*\*\@!\|\*\@<!\*[^* ]\@=" end="[^* ]\@<=\*\|\*\@<!\*[^* ]\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
syn region markdownItalic start="[^_ ]\@<=__\@!\|_\@<!_[^_]\@=" end="[^_ ]\@<=_\|_\@<!_[^_]\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
```

Also, notably, it seems Tim Pope's current [vim-markdown](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown) does not have the problem (though as of this writing it has others related to italics; it seems this is a difficult problem to solve with Vim syntax highlighting).